# How to read only some previously know lines using ifstream (C++)

Tags: c++, file, input, io

By preprocessing on the file i found some line for further processing, know i want to read that lines. is there any faster solution than reading lines one by one using `ifstream::getline(...)` ?

For example i know that i want only lines of product 4 (0-4-8-12-16-...) or special line numbers stored in a vector...

Now I'm doing this :

```
string line;
int counter = 0;
while( getline(ifstr,line) ){
   if(counter%4 =0){
      // some code working with line
   }
}
```

but i want something like this (if faster)

```
while(getline(ifstr,line)){ 
  // some code working with line
  while(++counter%4 !=0){ // or checking on index vector
     skipline(ifstr)         
  }
}
```

Let me mention again that i have some line index (sorted but not this regular) but i use this example of product4 for simplicity.

Edit: and i want to jump to line at the begining, for example i know that i need to read from line number 2000, how to skip 1999 lines quickly ?
Thanks all

Comment: Instead of line numbers, could you store file offsets (as obtained by `tellg()`)? Then you can jump to one later with `seekg()`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik it is hard to store file offsets in my case, is this a fast way to use? as i want to read some lines in a sorted manner i thing reading and skipping is better... no?

Comment: Unfortunately C and C++ have no concept of lines. Fundamentally, reading in a file by line requires finding and seeking to the next `\n`, which requires checking each character in between the current character and the next `\n`. There are relatively efficient ways to do that, but Igor is right that you will get the best performance by storing the character positions of the beginnings of the lines you care about.

Comment: Why not save the interesting lines when you first find them, during the preprocessing, and not
have to read the input file again at all?

Comment: @MikeKinghan Because of BIG DATA and additionally i find them through some processing on a table, not processing the lines of the file

Comment: @ameerosein if you found one of the answers useful, you should accept it or at least leave a comment expressing why it is not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because @caps said this left him with the feeling there's nothing in the standard library to help with this kind of task, I felt compelled to demonstrate otherwise :)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4667383a8e5b5248)</kbd>**

```
template <typename It, typename Out, typename Filter = std::vector<int> >
Out retrieve_lines(It begin, It const end, Filter lines, Out out, char const* delim = "\\n") {
    if (lines.empty())
        return out;

    // make sure input is orderly
    assert(std::is_sorted(lines.begin(), lines.end()));
    assert(lines.front() >= 0);

    std::regex re(delim);
    std::regex_token_iterator<It> line(begin, end, re, -1), eof;

    // make lines into incremental offsets
    std::adjacent_difference(lines.begin(), lines.end(), lines.begin());

    // iterate advancing by each offset requested
    auto advanced = [&line, eof](size_t n) { while (line!=eof && n--) ++line; return line; };

    for (auto offset = lines.begin(); offset != lines.end() && advanced(*offset) != eof; ++offset) {
        *out++ = *line;
    }

    return out;
}
```

This is noticably more generic. The trade off (for now) is that the tokenizing iterator requires a random access iterator. I find this a good trade-off because "random access" on files really asks for memory mapped files anyways

### Live Demo 1: from string to `vector<string>`

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f39662447ab9044)</kbd>**

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> output_lines;
    std::string is(" a b c d e\nf g hijklmnop\nqrstuvw\nxyz");

    retrieve_lines(is.begin(), is.end(), {0,3,999}, back_inserter(output_lines));

    // for debug purposes
    for (auto& line : output_lines)
        std::cout << line << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
 a b c d e
xyz
```

### Live Demo 2: From file to `cout`

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81ce06471ca1081b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
int main() {
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source is("/etc/dictionaries-common/words");

    retrieve_lines(is.begin(), is.end(), {13,784, 9996}, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
ASL's
Apennines
Mercer's
```

> The use of `boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source` can easily be replaced with straight up [`::mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) but I found it uglier in the presentation sample.

Comment: What I said was that I didn't see anything in the [standard library algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) that was applicable.

What I should have specified was that there is nothing applicable if you want to consume the entire input stream in `O(N)` for the number of characters in a file (i.e. a single pass) when using `input_iterator`s like I was.

Comment: @caps I get your drift. In this case I think it wasn't required. I may find some time tonight to see whether I can cobble together something elegant. (I think it would still significantly be using standard algorithms)

Comment: Silly me forgetting to actually use `istreambuf_iterator<char>` now that it can http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40084500c1f58f19

Comment: This is clean, but it won't bail early if you find all the lines you need with, say, 10k to go.

Comment: @caps Yup. Excellent point. I'll think about a more general version.

Answer (score 2):

Store `std::fstream::streampos` instances corresponding to line beginnings of your file into a `std::vector` and then you can access a specific line using the index of this vector. A possible implementation follows,

```
class file_reader {
public:
    // load file streampos offsets during construction
    explicit file_reader(const std::string& filename) 
        : fs(filename) { cache_file_streampos(); }
    std::size_t lines() const noexcept { return line_streampos_vec.size(); }
    // get a std::string representation of specific line in file
    std::string read_line(std::size_t n) {
        if (n >= line_streampos_vec.size() - 1)
            throw std::out_of_range("out of bounds");
        navigate_to_line(n);
        std::string rtn_str;
        std::getline(fs, rtn_str);
        return rtn_str;
    }
private:
    std::fstream fs;
    std::vector<std::fstream::streampos> line_streampos_vec;
    const std::size_t max_line_length = // some sensible value
    // store file streampos instances in vector
    void cache_file_streampos() {
        std::string s;
        s.reserve(max_line_length);
        while (std::getline(fs, s)) 
            line_streampos_vec.push_back(fs.tellg());
    }
    // go to specific line in file stream
    void navigate_to_line(std::size_t n) {
        fs.clear();
        fs.seekg(line_streampos_vec[n]);
    }
};
```

Then you can read a specific line of your file via,

```
file_reader fr("filename.ext");
for (int i = 0; i < fr.lines(); ++i) {
    if (!(i % 4))
        std::string line_contents = fr.read_line(i); // then do something with the string 
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it is not quite a solution to the OP's question.

Comment: Comments on code clarity: I suggest `expected_line_length` instead of `max_line_length`. The latter is misleading, since a string can grow past what you `reserve`; it is not really a max.

Answer (score 1):

ArchbishopOfBanterbury's answer is nice, and I would agree with him that you will get cleaner code and better efficiency by just storing the character positions of the beginning of each line when you do your preprocessing.

But, supposing that is not possible (perhaps the preprocessing is handled by some other API, or is from user input), there is a solution that should do the minimal amount of work necessary to read in only the specified lines.

The fundamental problem is that, given a file with variable line lengths, you cannot know where each line begins and ends, since a line is defined as a sequence of characters that end in `'\n'`. So, you must parse every character to check and see if it is `'\n'` or not, and if so, advance your line counter and read in the line if the line counter matches one of your desired inputs.

```
auto retrieve_lines(std::ifstream& file_to_read, std::vector<int> line_numbers_to_read) -> std::vector<std::string>
{
    auto begin = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file_to_read);
    auto end = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>();

    auto current_line = 0;
    auto next_line_num = std::begin(line_numbers_to_read);

    auto output_lines = std::vector<std::string>();
    output_lines.reserve(line_numbers_to_read.size());  //this may be a silly "optimization," since all the strings are still separate unreserved buffers

    //we can bail if we've reached the end of the lines we want to read, even if there are lines remaining in the stream
    //we *must* bail if we've reached the end of the stream, even if there are supposedly lines left to read; that input must have been incorrect
    while(begin != end && next_line_num != std::end(line_numbers_to_read))
    {
        if(current_line == *next_line_num)
        {
            auto matching_line = std::string();
            if(*begin != '\n')
            {
                //potential optimization: reserve matching_line to something that you expect will fit most/all of your input lines
                while(begin != end && *begin != '\n')
                {
                    matching_line.push_back(*begin++);
                }
            }
            output_lines.emplace_back(matching_line);
            ++next_line_num;
        }
        else 
        {
            //skip this "line" by finding the next '\n'
            while(begin != end && *begin != '\n')
            {
                ++begin;
            }
        }

        //either code path in the previous if/else leaves us staring at the '\n' at the end of a line,
        //which is not the right state for the next iteration of the loop.
        //So skip this '\n' to get to the beginning of the next line
        if (begin != end && *begin == '\n')
        {
            ++begin;
        }

        ++current_line;
    }

    return output_lines;
}
```

Here it is live on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c43728783960af4c), along with the [input I tested it with](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6252a5db711d1290). As you can see, it correctly handles empty lines as well as correctly handling being told to grab more lines than are in the file.